# How to dual boot ubuntu and other distro?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a FAT32 formatted USB flash drive and I have burnt an ISO image in it using:

```
dd if=myiso.iso of=/dev/sdb1
```

When it completed, I tried to boot from the USB and got an error `Missing or corrupt OS` and then GRUB screen appeared after 2 seconds.

Is there anything I need to do to boot from USB?

Answer (score 2):

What utility did you use to "burn" the image onto the flash drive?  Simply copying the file won't work.

I have more experience using [unetbootin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/), but [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) which is explicitly made for what you are trying to do, comes included with Ubuntu